# Searching for error handling solution when firehose is down

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-kinesis-firehose

### **My system background:**

I have a Scala application that read events from various queue technologies, transform the data and as final step send record to kinesis firehose.
My firehose is currently have S3 bucket as destination, but I don't want to bind it to the solution, since it could be changed in the future.

### **Problem statement**

AWS guarantees a monthly uptime percentage of at least 99.9% (means ~44 minutes in a month) - See [Service Level Agreement](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-firehose/faqs/).
In addition, when quota limits are reached, putRecord will return ServiceUnavailableException - See [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html).

As part of the flow I can't afford events loss, so I'm searching for sort of solution for firehose unavailability.

We think about error handler that will:

- Publish to SQS each event that failed to published into firehose.
- When firehose get back to work, SNS will trigger AWS Lambda.
- AWS Lambda will publish all events from SQS into firehose.

### **My question**

I'm wondering if that solution is good enough and if there is best practice for handling errors when trying to putRecord into firehose?

Comment: But that what;s going to happen when SQS, SNS or lambda fail? All of them are regional services, and AWS regions do fail.

Comment: Technically, it could happened, but the likelihood that all services will be down at the same time is much smaller than only one will be down. In addition, failures to put records into firehose could be cause even if firehose is up (e.g: when you publish more records than the limit, firehose will return ServiceUnavailableException)